# Odoo 9 error: ImportError: No module named faces

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have an error:

> ImportError: No module named faces on code from
>   openerp.addons.resource.faces import task as Task.

I understand that in odoo-9 addons there are only addon called resourse but no directory called faces inside. I tried to search maybe odoo changed name or something but can't find anything..

Comment: `faces` is a task allocation library that used to be included in the `resource` module until Odoo 8: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/resource/faces It has been removed in Odoo 9 as it was mostly unused. If you see this error in Odoo 9 perhaps your installation is invalid or the `addons_path` includes Odoo 8?

Comment: Yeah, I have addon which was in Odoo 7 addons_paths and I want to use it for Odoo 9 version. So that's why I get this error. So as I understand I have just delete this: "from openerp.addons.resource.faces import task as Task" and thats it?